# Botium Bindings with Dialogflow connector works for Mocha but not Jest

Tags: jestjs, mocha.js, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I've followed the installation instructions [here](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-dialogflow).

When I use npm run mocha my test convos run successfully using my dialogflow settings in botium.json.
If I follow the same process for Jest (my preferred framework) the process always fails with this error:

```
Loading Botium plugin failed at Validate.Validate.then (node_modules/botium-core/src/containers/PluginConnectorContainer.js:99:15)
```

If I revert botium.json to

```
"CONTAINERMODE": "echo",
```

The tests run (but fail as expected).

Is there any additional set up needed to use BotiumBindings and dialogflow connector with Jest?

Comment: I am also experiencing troubles with Jest - other connectors are not working with Jest as well. As a temporary workaround, please use mocha. Honestly, I currently have no idea what's the problem, it seems as if Jest is using completly different 3rd party libraries than mocha.

Answer (score 0):

In your file *package.json*, add the switch *--env node* when running jest. The dialogflow client library won't work in Node.js without this switch.

```
...
"scripts": {
  "jest": "jest --env node spec"
},
...
```